# How to index tensor by using all but given indices in pytorch?

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch

Suppose I have a Tensor `a`

```
>>> a
tensor([[2, 8],
        [3, 0],
        [4, 2],
        [2, 2],
        [6, 8]])
```

I also have a tensor `idx` consisting of indices that I don't want to select

```
>>> idx
tensor([0, 3, 4])
```

How should I go ahead and select all rows except the ones whose indices are present in the tensor `idx`?
For the above tensors `a` and `idx`, after selection, I should get the output Tensor `b` as

```
>>> b
tensor([[3, 0],
        [4, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a[[i for i in range(len(a)) if i not in idx]]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am looking for solutions that don't use a for loop so that the resulting operation can take advantage of GPUs